# Ember.Handlebars.compile fails

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I'm totally new to Ember and I'm actually trying to organize my code a bit. To do so, I try to load my Handlebars templates from external files. Everything works fine until the moment I want to compile them.

```
var url = 'js/app/templates/index.hbs', templateName = url.replace('.hbs', ''), 
    datas = {name:'John'};

var load_tpl_success = function(hbs_tpl) {
    Em.TEMPLATES[templateName] = Em.Handlebars.compile(hbs_tpl)(datas);
    Em.$('body').append(Em.TEMPLATES[templateName]);
};

Em.$.ajax({ url: url, async: false, success: load_tpl_success});
```

This crashes and gives me te error : **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'push' of undefined**

BUT, if I use :

```
Handlebars.compile(hbs_tpl)(datas)
```

Everything works well until I start using {{input}} and others made by Ember. So basically it looks like Handlebars is working but not Ember... I need Ember ahah

I'm using the last version of Ember coming with its own Handlebars (old version).

Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Em.Handlebars.compile` returns a template function that can be used for rendering. You are creating the template, then immediately calling the function to compile the template.

```
Em.TEMPLATES[templateName] = Em.Handlebars.compile(hbs_tpl)(datas);
```

That line is not creating a template, it's creating one *then* rendering it. So while Ember.js is expect a template, you're giving it a rendered template (a string). You should never be directly calling the template method, that is done for you by Ember.js. So this line is a **big** no-no.

```
Em.$('body').append(Em.TEMPLATES[templateName]);
```

The only thing you should be doing with templates is creating them and telling Ember.js where they are. You can either do that by including them in the HTML via `script` tags, or by putting them in the `Em.TEMPLATES` hash. But if you're doing the latter, make sure you don't attempt to go to the route using that template before you put it there.

TL;DR: You're too new too Ember.js to be worrying about pre-compiling or lazy-loading templates. Put them in `script` tags like in the guide until you're more familiar with their workings.

EDIT: Also, this applies in general, but especially when working with Ember.js: **never** run a synchronous AJAX request. There are very few times you'd want to do that, and this is not one of them.